# How to do time-data in D3 maps

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, time-series, geojson

I have a time-series dataset that I'd like to put on a map---it's an irregular times series of incidents in countries, indexed by date and country.  I've used D3 for a couple simple things, but am unsure how to organize the data here, even conceptually.  I've checked...

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606
- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306362
- http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/4188334

for map-making, and am comfortable generating the .json map itself:

```
wget "http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip"
unzip ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output_features.json ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp -select iso_a3
topojson -o topo.json output_features.json --id-property iso_a3
```

However, when my data looks like this...

```
incidents.csv
date, iso3, eventtype
2001-05-21, ABW, a
2002-01-01, ABW, a
2005-07-31, ABW, b
2003-02-21, AFG, b
2008-02-21, AFG, c
2000-03-09, AGO, a
2010-06-11, AGO, c
```

I'm at a loss for how to even "attach" this to the map figure---time is a whole other dimension.  Does each country-shape get a time vector attached to it, that includes an "eventtype" as well?  All the event types?  How?

On the one hand, I could see utility in aggregating certain things ahead of time, to the level of...

```
ABW, a, 2 
ABW, b, 1
ABW, c, 0
AFG, a, 0
AFG, b, 1
AFG, c, 1
AGO, a, 1
AGO, b, 0
AGO, c, 1
```

...and attaching this somehow and that could probably produce a fine choropleth.

But I'd actually really like to keep the time component. Ideally, I'd like to have 2 slider bars at the bottom of the map that I can use to only show aggregations of types of events that happen between a given start and end-date.

I'm good with python and time-series data, but I recognize I'm a bit beyond my skills here with D3---how would I get started, and what's the preferred way to attach to and work with categorical, irregular time-series data in topojson in D3?  How would I solve this?

(I also have a [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70511/d3-for-maps-at-what-stage-to-bring-in-data-to-the-geo) about workflow on the gis stackexchange that's less complex.)

Comment: It sounds like you would want to use 2 different files. One for the geography and one for the data. That is, all your map data comes from one file with IDs for each country that link them to events that are specified (with time etc) in a second file.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but have you looked at [Cubism.js](http://square.github.io/cubism/) (also by @mbostock) for displaying your time-series data?  I just read about it in the book ["Interactive Data Visualization for the web"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026938.do)

Comment: Yeah, it's cool, but slightly different usecase, this won't be streaming.  I just want to be able to tweak the counts on the choropleth based on time sliders.

Answer (score 0):

I think a temporary answer I'll fill in for anyone else looking at this question:

Time on a map is really hard, and kind of non-generic.  You'll be spending a lot of time with proper interface-design.